# Adding a search bar and search display controller to a map view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, android-mapview, searchbar

I am trying to add a search bar and search display to a map view. I don't actually care how to handle the search request, my current problem is how to add a search bar and search display controller to a map view and how to set it up. I could't find any up to date documentation about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add and bind Searchbar Controller to your viewcontroller

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    //Don't forget to add <UISearchBarDelegate> into your .h file
    yourSearchbar.delegate=self;
}

//implement search bar delegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",searchBar.text);

    //next you've to setup logic to pass search text to your mapview
}
```

Comment: and what about search display?
And can you do this with interface builder?

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520223/search-bar-display-controller)

Comment: I have seen it. My problem is - I cant find any documantation on search display controller. Also, I am very curious why can't I add a search bar in interface builder to a map view, while I can add it to a table view.